# Adding project reference prevents windows service from starting - error 1053

Tags: c#, .net, azure, windows-services

I am writing a windows service that installs and runs successfully.

After I try to add a little sophistication to the service by referencing another project in my solution, when I try to start the service I get:

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

The references which are homemade API's are .net 4.5 and the MS class libraries are 4.0. Also, I have tried changing my build type to `Release`.

For what it's worth, the API's I'm trying to reference are using the Azure Service Bus. Also, we have quite a bit of dependency injection going on using ninject.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service inherits from `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`, which I'm assuming it does, try wrapping a console app around it to test the start up.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var myService = new MyService();
        myService.OnStart(args);
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

That might point to either a config or environment error that is being hidden by the service host.